# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to develope an application with codeigniter and I'm trying to find a mistake here which I don't find. The code is the next one:

```
<?php foreach($projects as $key => $project){ ?>
        <li <?php if ($current_project == $project['id']): ?>class="active"<? endif; ?>><a href="<?php echo $base_url . config_item('language_abbr') ?>/<?= $project['id'] ?>/admin/galerias"><?php echo $project['nombre']?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Before of this I had:

```
<?php foreach($projects as $key => $project): ?>
        <li <?php if ($current_project == $project['id']): ?>class="active"<? endif; ?>><a href="<?php echo $base_url . config_item('language_abbr') ?>/<?= $project['id'] ?>/admin/galerias"><?php echo $project['nombre']?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And instead of moaning about the }, it moans about the endforeach; , so what happen?.

And this is the code of the zone where is located the mistake because when I remove this part of code, it works:

```
<?php if (!empty($user_id) && $isAdmin): ?>
    <nav>
     <ul class="nav">
       <li 
          <?php if ($current_project == 0): ?>
            class="active"
            <? endif; ?>>
               <a href="<?php echo $base_url . config_item('language_abbr') ?>/0/admin/proyectos"><?= t('h_all'); ?></a>
        </li>

        <?php 
            foreach($projects as $key => $project){ ?>
                 <li 
                  <?php if ($current_project == $project['id']): ?>
                  class="active"<? endif; ?>>
                     <a href="<?php echo $base_url . config_item('language_abbr') ?>/<?= $project['id'] ?>/admin/galerias"><?php echo $project['nombre']?></a>
                 </li>
            <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks so much

Comment: There is a lot of different php opening tags here - some are obviously to echo out content and do not require the `php` but there are some that are used in flow control (`if/then/else`) and these do not echo out content yet do not have the `php` either. I realise these may be valid but things like `<? endif; ?>>` ought to remain consistent with the other tag styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not exactly the style of solution you were looking for but it is quite easy to read to find potential mistakes.

```
<?php
    foreach( $projects as $key => $project ){
        $class=( $current_project==$project['id'] ) ? " class='active'" : '';

        echo "
        <li{$class}>
            <a href='".$base_url . config_item('language_abbr')."/".$project['id']."/admin/galerias'>".$project['nombre']."</a>
        </li>";
    }
?>
```

The offending portion of code where you believe the error might lie in a similar style to my original answer - to my mind it is much easier to read and therefore much easier to spot where mistakes are - though it is a personal preference I guess and the style used in the original code seems to be more popular these days.

```
<?php
    if ( !empty( $user_id ) && $isAdmin ){

        $class=( $current_project == 0 ) ? " class='active'" : '';
        $lang=config_item('language_abbr');
        $linktext=t('h_all');

        echo "
        <nav>
            <ul class='nav'>
                <li{$class}><a href='{$base_url}{$lang}/0/admin/proyectos'>{$linktext}</a></li>";

        foreach( $projects as $key => $project ){
            $class=( $current_project == $project['id'] ) ? " class='active'" : '';
            echo "<li{$class}><a href='{$base_url}/{$lang}/{$project['id']}/admin/galerias'>{$project['nombre']}</a></li>";
        }

        echo "
            </ul>
        </nav>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: After change these lines by what you wrote I have no unexpected end of file.

Comment: make sure error reporting is on ( `error_reporting( E_ALL );` ) to debug and check the logs for a particular line - the code above doesn't appear to have any errors ~ or maybe I'm just not awake enough yet?!

Comment: I have add the whole file, because I don't understand why I have this mistake

Comment: the code is very hard to read due to the lack on indentation and the lack of curly braces. All I can suggest is to look in the error log for where the error is occurring, make sure error_reporting is on and perhaps temporarily remove portions of the code to see if you can isolate where the problem is. I'm guessing but I would think you have failed to close an `IF` / `THEN` / `ELSE` statemet somewhere - good luck

Comment: I have reduce the code where is the mistake and it's clean and clear now

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($projects as $key => $project){ ?>
 <li <?php if ($current_project == $project['id']): ?>class="active"<? endif; ?>>
<a href="<?php echo $base_url . config_item('language_abbr') ?>/<?= $project['id'] ?>/admin/galerias">
 <?php echo $project['nombre'];?></a></li> <?php } ?>
```

You were missing a semi colon after
    $project['nombre']

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
<?php
foreach($projects as $key => $project){
echo "<li ".($current_project == $project['id'])?"class=active":""." ><a href='".$base_url . config_item('language_abbr').$project['id']."/admin/galerias' >$project[nombre]</a></li>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php foreach($projects as $key => $project){ 
         $class = $current_project == $project['id']) ? 'active' : '';
   ?>
         <li class="<?=$class;?>"><a href="<?php echo $base_url . config_item('language_abbr') ?>/<?= $project['id'] ?>/admin/galerias"><?php echo $project['nombre']?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: you have an unbalanced brace `$current_project == $project['id'])`